# How to update shopware 6 docker local setup while persisting existing data?

Tags: shopware6

```
./psh.phar install
```

doing so installs required dependencies but also make fresh installation of demodata and drops the existing data. How do you continue persisting existing data and update the system locally?

Answer (score 3):

There is a `./psh.phar update` command, that will execute all new database migrations etc. in place, that is probably what you were looking for.